# Spring MVC HTTP 404 error

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

I learning SpringMVC so I am followed Spring 3.0 MVC Series from [HERE](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/).

As you can see, I completed Part1, Part2, and I am right now on Part3 where I am learning how to handle forms with Spring 3 MVC.

But I get this HTTP 404 eror, when I try to run my application. Project strucutre and this error you can see at image below.

How I can fix this?

[image]

**ContactController.java code:**

```
package net.viralpatel.spring3.controller;

import net.virtalpatel.spring3.form.Contact;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class ContactController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact")
Contact contact, BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("First Name:" + contact.getFirstname() + 
                "Last Name:" + contact.getLastname());

    return "redirect:contacts.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/contacts")
public ModelAndView showContacts() {

    return new ModelAndView("contact", "command", new Contact());
}}
```

**spring-servlet.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

****index.jsp code:****

```
<jsp:forward page="contacts.html"></jsp:forward>
```

**web.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what is the url tried

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/index.jsp As you can see, I try first to open index.jsp and then redirect to contact.jsp

Comment: Hi @Zookey i am running into same situation badly, could you please help me out on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697899/how-to-map-dynamic-url-prj-noticeopen-2-in-spring-mvc-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `contact` to `contacts`

change

`return new ModelAndView("contact", "command", new Contact());`

to

`return new ModelAndView("contacts", "command", new Contact());`

The issue is in your forward it will check for the contact.jsp but actually you have contacts.jsp (you have suffix property as .jsp )

Comment: Unbelievable what a mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Krisl i am running into same situation badly, could you please help me out on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697899/how-to-map-dynamic-url-prj-noticeopen-2-in-spring-mvc-controller

Comment: @Rey, I think you have got the answer and fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

your `index.jsp` is forwarded to `contacts.html`.

But you spring configuration does not have mapping for `/contacts.html`, you have mapped `/contacts` instead.

You need to change the `/contacts` mapping to

```
@RequestMapping("/contacts.html")
public ModelAndView showContacts() {
    return new ModelAndView("contact", "command", new Contact());
}
```

Comment: I changed that, but I stil get this error. As you can see from the image: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/B/q7/3F9RnEc/error2.png

Comment: it is going to `/contacts.jsp`, can you try the url `/Spring3MVC/contacts.html`

Comment: When I try /Spring3MVC/contacts.html I get same error as on the image.

Answer (score 0):

> localhost:8080/Spring3MVC/index.jsp As you can see, I try first to open index.jsp and then redirect to contact.jsp – Zookey 44 mins ago

I think you have it mixed up. 1) There is a typo, you say contact.jsp but the file name is contacts.jsp (file name in eclipse)
2) Where is the contacts.html file ?
I would suggest, you first return to the jsp and see if you can get your controller to return the jsp after that try redirecting to the html file after you create one.

Comment: It's contacts.jsp. I dont have contacts.html file, I have just contacts.jsp.